# Angular open detail page from list

Tags: angular, components

```
`
//this is the list 
export class ListComponent implements OnInit {
  books: Book[];
  constructor(private service:HalkaApiService){ }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.service.getBooks().subscribe((data)=>{
      this.books=data;
    });
  }

//this is the service

getBooks():Observable<Book[]>{
   return this.http.get<Book[]>(this.path + "/Books");
}
getBook(id:number|string){
  return this.http.get<Book[]>(this.path + `/Books ${id}`);
}
`
```

I want to go to the book-detail component  when I click the "details" link in the list-Html file

Answer (score 1):

First, you display the books in the booklist component.html like so:

```html
<div *ngIf="books.length>0">
<ul *ngFor="let book of books">
<li> {{book.details}} - <a routerLink = "book-detail"/{{book.id}}">{{book.name}}</>
</li>
</ul>
```

Then create another component called book-detail, do the routing to be
{path:'book-detail/:id', component:BookDetailComponent}, in the routing module.

Then in the BookDetail component, do this:

```js
export class BookDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  book:Book;
  constructor(private service:HalkaApiService, private activatedRoute:ActivatedRoute){ }

  ngOnInit() {
  this.activatedRoute.paramMap.pipe(
      switchMap((params: ParamMap) => this.service.getBook(params.get('productId'))
      )
    ).subscribe(result => { this.book = result; }, error => console.error(error));
  }
```

Then in the book-detail.component.html do this to display the book details:

```html
<div *ngIf="book">
  <p> {{book.title}}</p>
  <p> written by {{book.author}}, released {{book.releaseYear}}</p>
  <p> {{book.summary}}
</div>
```

And that is all. I hope you understand.
Thanks

Comment: suggestion: instead of using `div` for the `*ngIf="book"` and `*ngIf="books.length>0"`, use `<ng-container></ng-container>`. The `div` would get added in the DOM and you don't actually need it. `ng-container`s do not get added in the DOM, so this element is perfect for this kind of checks or observable subscriptions like `<ng-container (someData$ | async) as data> . . . </ng-container>`

Comment: Wow! we learn everyday. I never knew this before today. I will keep using <ng-container> .Thanks

Comment: I got errors because of the switchMap part. Is there any alternative way?

Comment: Can I see the error? Did you import ActivatedRoute?

You can use this too: 

this.service.getBook(this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params.get('id')).subscribe(response=>{
this.book = response;
}, error => console.error(error)););